# Programmatically generate MIDI and play with VST instrument/effects to wav file?

Tags: wav, midi, vst

What web language/framework would you recommend to accomplish the following:

1. Programmatically create basic MIDI files from scratch, such as melodies, scales, and chords.
2. Programmatically play those MIDI files using a VST
   instrument to a .wav output file (such as a Grand Piano VST
   instrument).
3. It would also be very nice to use other VST effects and
   processors along with the VST instrument, such as reverbs and
   compression to make it sound professional.
4. I'd like to do this all dynamically in a web program, so that no GUIs are needed for the VST instruments/effects.

Ideally it would look like this:

Program creates MIDI file based on user input > MIDI file is played by VST instrument > VST effects & processors are applied > Output .wav file

This will be a proof-of-concept for a more adventurous program.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[VST.NET](http://vstnet.codeplex.com) for 2.x VST plugins (and hosts) in C# or VB.NET
[MIDI.NET](http://midinet.codeplex.com) for Windows MIDI support in C# or VB.NET
And in my [repository project](http://cannedbytes.codeplex.com/) there is generic code to work with WAV files (.NET)

Should be pretty quick to get going.
[2c]